# ResultSet - Cursor : rs.next() Taking lot of time

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a cursor returned from Database executes in 31ms (milliseconds) .

But when I use this cursor having more than 1500 rows for fetching rows

```
  ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)cstm.getObject(6);

  while(rs.next()){
     system.out.println("...");
  }
```

Just simple transversing through each row of cursor it's taking more than 40 seconds (40000 ms)

What can be done?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Indeed, by default JDBC use a fetch size of 10.
Thus, if you don't set a greater value, you'll call database for next records exactly 150 times ..., no need to explain drawbacks of round-trips.

All you have to do is to test performance by setting `fetchSize` to.. **100** for instance :

```
statement.setFetchSize(100);
```

You can play with this number to improve performance according to your environnement.

Answer (score 6):

you have more than 1500 rows in your **cursor** and the **rs** what is returned by the database is just a reference to that cursor. So when you invoke **rs.next()**, every time it goes to the database cursr and get you the current record pointed by the cursor pointer.

So obviously it will take some time to go to database every time and fetch a single record for more than 1500 times with every while loop iteration.

Comment: Nice explanation.